# Trouble aligning insert button

Tags: jquery, css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

I'm trying to center a button on a shop not sure how to go about this.

```
<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--logo">            
   <label for="custom_photo">Upload your photo of pet/s</label>
   <input required id="custom_photo" type="file" name="properties[Logo]" class="product-form__input">           
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try? Do you want to center in which location? Please show us some more code in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I do asume that you're willing to outline the div in the center.

You can do that by adding a separate CSS file or by adding it directly towards the HTML element. In the example below we've added the following tag towards the HTML div:

```
style="text-algin:center"
```

for example:

```html
<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--logo" style="text-align:center">            
   <label for="custom_photo">Upload your photo of pet/s</label>
   <input required id="custom_photo" type="file" name="properties[Logo]" class="product-form__input">           
</div>
```

Comment: Im trting to center the text for "upload photo of your pet"
Would it be:
<label for="custom_photo">Upload your photo of pet/s</label> style="text-algin:center"

or 
<label for="custom_photo">Upload your photo of pet/s style="text-algin:center"</label>

Comment: It would be <label for="custom_photo" style="text-align:center">...</label>. But I asume you want to have it on a separated line so add a <br/> after it. Let me know if this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Nah that's not doing it i'm in a liquid file im not to sure if that's css? this is what my outcome is right now using the text in original post https://imgur.com/a/kZYnQkp addint that style just adds it to the displayed text. Im just trying to move the "Choose file" bit of it to center the text